# Visual Studio 2017 - break when a variable is read

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, breakpoints

I use Visual Studio 2017 for C++ projects. I can set a data breakpoint to break when a value of the variable is changed. Is it possible to set a breakpoint when a variable is just read, for example:

```
int x = 5;
//somewhere in the code
int y = x; //break when x is read
```

?

I would like to break every time the variable `x` is read.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [that explains difference between property and fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295104/what-is-the-difference-between-a-field-and-a-property)

Instead of just a variable creation, if you have a property, you would be able to set a breakpoint at EITHER the getter (value is being read/accessed) or setter (assigning a value TO)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for C++.